# Como decodificar uma imagem em Base64

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou tentando decodificar uma imagem , a string que vem como parâmetro no atributo Image do objeto post é assim: "data:image/png;base64," e um monte de letras, numeros, e simbolos a direita,

quero decodificar e conseguir a imagem original para salvar em um diretório, é possível?
tentei usar o Convert.FromBase64String contudo nao obtive sucesso, alguem tem ideia de oque seja?

```
public void NewPost(Post post)
        {
           post.Image = post.Image.Replace("data:image/png;base64,", "");
           byte[] byteObject = Convert.FromBase64String(post.Image);
           .
           .
           .
           .

        }
```

Comment: Não entendi: em teoria quando você codifica uma imagem pra Base64, é o conteúdo dela inteiro, e não a URL. Está certo isso?

Comment: Cigano, sim, vc esta correto, foi erro meu colocar o atributo como imageURL, vou editar, vlw

Comment: @Ukyron tem como você disponibilizar o valor dessa base64?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disponibilizar a string base64 da imagem ajudaria bastante!

De qualquer forma, segue:

```
[TestMethod]
public void como_decodificar_uma_imagem_em_base64()
{
    var img = "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";

    var decoder = new DecodificarImagem();

    var imgStrm = decoder.DecodeBase64(img);

    imgStrm.Should().NotBeEmpty();
}
```

E a classe:

```
public class DecodificarImagem
{
    public byte[] DecodeBase64(string img)
    {
        img = FixBase64ForImage(img);
        return Convert.FromBase64String(img);
    }

    public string FixBase64ForImage(string Image) { 
        System.Text.StringBuilder sbText = new System.Text.StringBuilder(Image, Image.Length); 
        sbText.Replace("\r\n", String.Empty); 
        sbText.Replace(" ", "+"); 
        return sbText.ToString(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: o método FixBase64ForImage resolveu meu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente é assim:

```
public void NewPost(Post post)
{
    post.Image = post.Image.Replace("data:image/png;base64,", "");
    byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(post.Image);

    Image image;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    {
        image = Image.FromStream(ms);
    }

    image.Save(caminhoDoDiscoPraSalvar, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

Não sei que formato que está, mas o exemplo salva em JPEG.

Comment: Cigano, na hora da conversão, estou tentando usar o metodo Convert.FromBase64String, só que da um erro assim: "Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string." mas se eu copiar a string e colar esses decoders que tem na internet ele decofifica perfeitamente para mim, tem ideia?

Comment: Acho que a minha resposta tá errada mesmo. Se quiser editar pro jeito que funciona, fique à vontade.