# Como enviar e receber imagem pelo json?

Tags: c#, json

eu fiz um app em Xamarin que a pessoa terá que assinar e preciso mandar essa imagem para o servidor
Se possível deixar o código para realizar tal tarefa

Comment: Uma das estratégias possíveis é usar base64 e transformar os bytes da imagem em texto. Depois o servidor precisa saber disso e remover a transformação base64.

Comment: Como realizo tal tarefa, o maior problema é para desconverter

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/20683/64969

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como decodificar uma imagem em Base64](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/20683/como-decodificar-uma-imagem-em-base64)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que eu tenho é uma Stream que preciso mandar para o servidor
então ficou assim

```
 Atendimento_ViewModel.Assinatura = await Pad.GetImageStreamAsync(SignatureImageFormat.Png) as  MemoryStream;
app local
byte[] imageBytes = Assinatura.ToArray();
pedido.Assinatura = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
```

Servidor

```
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(pedido.Assinatura);
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
Image Image1 = Image.GetInstance(System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream),System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

o código acima é para pegar a assinatura escrita e ser mandada para o servidor, atenção se a intenção for mandar a imagem em um pdf a mesma deve ser .pdf

Answer (score 1):

Basicamente, supondo que você tenha a imagem armazenada localmente, ou simplesmente tenha o byte array dela:

```
byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(FileName);
String strImage = Convert.ToBase64String(b);
```

Depois você envia isso pro servidor, como uma parâmetro string qualquer.

No servidor, pra você fazer o processo inverso:

```
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(strDaImagemRecebida);

Image image;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
{
    image = Image.FromStream(ms);
}
```